# Regarding printf use in nested for loop (multiplication table)

Tags: java

Have a problem with my output when creating a multiplication table 1-12 inclusive. below is my code and output

```
public class Multiplication
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int row,column;

        System.out.println("Below is a multiplication table from 1-12 inclusive");

        for (row=1;row<=12;row++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%4d\n",row);

            for (column=1;column<=12;column++)
                System.out.printf("%6d",row*column);
        }
    }
}
```

and my output is

Below is a multiplication table from 1-12 inclusive

```
   1
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12   2
     2     4     6     8    10    12    14    16    18    20    22    24   3
     3     6     9    12    15    18    21    24    27    30    33    36   4
     4     8    12    16    20    24    28    32    36    40    44    48   5
     5    10    15    20    25    30    35    40    45    50    55    60   6
     6    12    18    24    30    36    42    48    54    60    66    72   7
     7    14    21    28    35    42    49    56    63    70    77    84   8
     8    16    24    32    40    48    56    64    72    80    88    96   9
     9    18    27    36    45    54    63    72    81    90    99   108  10
    10    20    30    40    50    60    70    80    90   100   110   120  11
    11    22    33    44    55    66    77    88    99   110   121   132  12
    12    24    36    48    60    72    84    96   108   120   132   144
```

My problem is in getting the far right column to be on the far left. I've tried researching why only the number '1' appears and then it jumps but cant find anything

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the first of your two `printf` statements.  You should just be able to replace it with `System.out.printf("\n");`.

(The "jump" to which you refer is a newline, which is represented by the `\n` character.)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (row=1;row<=12;row++)
{        
  System.out.printf("%4d",row);

  for (column=1;column<=12;column++)

  System.out.printf("%6d",row*column);
  if(column==12) System.out.printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Multiplication
{    
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int row,column;

        System.out.println("Below is a multiplication table from 1-12 inclusive");

        for (row=1;row<=12;row++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%4d",row);
            for (column=1;column<=12;column++)
                System.out.printf("%6d",row*column);
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```